# Trying to find a distribution for time dependent drought

Tags: distributions, bayesian, stochastic-processes

I would like to seek your support on a modelling issue for which I could not find relevant past postings or published literature resolve it.

I am running a cost benefit model to assess the impact of stochastic severe drought events occurring in every 4-7 years. These events affect the flows of five benefits from rangeland use by local pastoralists, including pasture, firewood, charcoal, building material and small seasonal agricultural production.

The dynamics of each of these benefits, in terms of their changes in sizes of annual (and aggregate) values under different land use options is affected by the probability of drought occurring over different time horizons of 15, 20, and 47 years, depending on the land use option in place.

Droughts can happen randomly any year from 4th to 7th year, and its effect can range between 50% and 90% loss of total annual values.

Question: How best the drought stochastic occurrence can be modelled such that both impact and year of occurrence vary randomly within the 50-90% and 4-7 years respectively.

Comment: Have you considered using actual data?  If so, what forms and amounts of data do you have?

Comment: We have limited data collected from questionnaire answered in focus groups but a simulation study was needed in addition to the information collected to account for possible values in each year. We're interested in trying to use a distribution (in R) that can account for the time varying negative contribution of droughts to the cost benefit analysis.